# How to make a table that has a composite key arranged by a certain one of them?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Update: after checking the code i found the problem which is this

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_OrdersList_ProductId",
                table: "OrdersList",
                column: "ProductId");
```

so i created a an empty migration removed the index from this column and added it to the other one.

The Question:

So i am using code first and i have a model that has a composite key(Product Id and OrderId) now when that table is created in my sql server database, its arranged by ProductId but i want it to be ordered by OrderId
here is some of the code that i wrote for the database

here is the model

```
public class OrderProductList
    {

        public virtual Order? Order { get; set; }
        
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public virtual Product? Product { get; set; }


        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the context part

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProductList>().HasKey(o => new {o.OrderId,o.ProductId});
```

here is what was wrote in the migration

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "OrdersList",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    OrderId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ProductId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_OrdersList", x => new { x.OrderId, x.ProductId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_OrdersList_Orders_OrderId",
                        column: x => x.OrderId,
                        principalTable: "Orders",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_OrdersList_Products_ProductId",
                        column: x => x.ProductId,
                        principalTable: "Products",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_OrdersList_ProductId",
                table: "OrdersList",
                column: "ProductId");
```

Now when i select the table it shows all the rows with productId that is 1 and then 2 etc.

i do not know if the order in matters or not

```
table.PrimaryKey("PK_OrdersList", x => new { x.OrderId, x.ProductId });
```

Comment: SQL Server is multi-threaded and does not store data in any particular order.   Often the same query will return data in different order. If order is important you need to add Order By to your query to get data in same order every time.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables are inherently unordered sets, and you should never rely on the order the rows are returned from a query unless you explicitly specify this order (i.e., use an `order by` clause).